# Javascript for click function not working on one page

Tags: jquery

The idea here is that whenever a user clicks on an image, he or she can view information about that person in the box above. It worked before and then all of a sudden it stopped. Here is the link to the page I am talking about and my code.

http://www.team3550.org/team/

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#team_pics img, #team_pics2 img').click(function(){
                $('#team_description').html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />' + $(this).next().html());
            });
        });
    </script>
        <div id="team_description">     
            <h1>Click on a picture below to learn more about a team member</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="team_container">
            <div id="team_pics">
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_chase.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding: 30px;"/>
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Chase Schweitzer</b></span><br>-Third year in FTC<br>-Designer, builder, webmaster<br>-Interests: programming (HTML, CSS, BASIC, Javascript, etc.), web design, music, writing<br>-Plays the guitar and violin</p></div>
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_annie.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding: 30px;"/>
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Annie Howard</b></span><br>-Second year in FTC<br>-Designer, builder, writer<br>-Interests: music, writing, history, anthropology<br>-Plays the ukelele, sings</p></div>
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_tanvi.png" width="100px"height="100px" style="padding: 30px;"/>
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Tanvi Yenna</b></span><br>-Second year in FTC<br>-Designer, builder, engineering notebook organizer<br>-Interests: designing, music, writing, and acting<br>-Plays the piano, guitar and ukelele; sings</p></div>
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_jordan.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding: 30px;"/>                
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Jordan Burklund</b></span><br>-Fourth year in FTC, two years in FLL<br>-Designer, builder, programmer<br>-Interests: robotics/mechatronics engineering, aviation, and music<br>-CLAD certified</p></div>              
            </div>
            <div id="team_pics2">                   
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_saketh.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding: 0px 30px;"/>        
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Saketh Undurty</b></span><br>-Fourth year in FTC, two years in FLL<br>-Designer, builder<br>-Interests: 3D modeling/design, architecture, and music<br>-Plays trumpet in concert band and jazz orchestra</p></div>
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_daniel.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding: 0px 30px;"/>
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Daniel Miller</b></span><br>-Third year in FTC<br>-Designer, builder, promotions<br>-Interests: architecture, graphic design, music<br>-Viola player, mime, and thespian</p></div>
                <img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/pixel_sidd.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding: 0px 30px;"/>
                <div class="caption"><p class="caption_paragraph"><span class="caption_header"><b>Sidd Somayajula</b></span><br>-Third year in FTC<br>-Designer, builder, webmaster<br>-Interests: medicine, math, web design, programming (HTML, CSS, BASIC, Javascript, etc.)<br>-Plays tennis</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your site seems to have some other issues. Check the console. Also, you shouldn't use multiple **$(document).ready functions** (I viewed the source of your site ).

Comment: @pmandell why not, out of curiosity? Does it hurt anything or is it a code smell thing?

Answer (score 1):

You do see how line 202 is throwing a TypeError, correct?

```
var top = $('#blog_right').offset().top - parseFloat($('#blog_right').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/,0));
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

I don't see any element with blog_right as an ID on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a breakpoint in your code at the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` call does not even stop.